# PL/SQL script to rename tables using select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, alter-table

Hey all I am tasked to write a script to rename tables. All though this sounds easy, there are a few other things to keep in mind. There is a table which contains all of the other tables which will need name changing. Something along the lines of Table consists of 3 columns, first column is unpartitionednm, second is originalnm, third partitionedtablenm.  I was told to use a select statement to select two tables, then use those tables to alter the names.  This is what I have so far:

```
declare
begin
  execute immediate 'select unpartitiontablenm "table1", originaltablenm "table2"
                     from tabletransformation                     
                     alter table table1
                     rename to table2';
end;
```

Now I tried to send him other ways to do this, such as a renaming parameter and just a simple script to accept which two tables he would like to rename but all those he did not want. Maybe I just dont understand why this way is better but oh well, what can you do when you need a paycheck.  Anyways, I need some help understand exactly what he would like me to do and how far off I am from it.  Thanks in advance.

*I understand the above code is wrong but it might give you a better understanding of how he described it to me.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT unpartitiontablenm, originaltablenm 
              FROM tableTransformation)
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE ' || i.unpartitiontablenm|| 
                  ' RENAME TO ' || i.originaltablenm ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Huh, I never thought about that. He always mentioned doing one table at a time, but maybe it was just a miscommunication.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @AdamHalegua - Note that this does `ALTER` one table at a time.

Comment: Thanks Justin but I found out he actually wanted this: 
`select 'rename table '||unpartitiontablenm||' to '||originaltablenm from tabletransformation;` It was a miscommunication on our part.